# Google map location picker wont navigate

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I've implemented a map using the google map location picker.

```
onPressed: () async {
        LocationResult? result = await showLocationPicker(
          context,
          key,
          initialCenter: LatLng(double.parse(lat), double.parse(long)),
          myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
          layersButtonEnabled: true,
          automaticallyAnimateToCurrentLocation: true,
          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation,
          language: 'en',
          countries: ['LK'],
          requiredGPS: true,
        );
        debugPrint("result = $result");
        assignCity(result);
      },
```

The initial center is the lat and long values of my current location.
When I open my map, the map details like roads and stuff wont load.Its just a plane canvas with a pointer And wont let me navigate and pick a location as well.

I have provided all permissions in the android manifest file and the google api works fine and it shows that I have requested.

please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use placepicker library for it: https://pub.dev/packages/place_picker

```
                     PlacePicker(
                                /// Add YOUR OWN KEY here.
                                apiKey:
                                'your api key',
                                onPlacePicked: (result) async {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                  setState(() {});
                                  if (result.geometry!.location.lat != null &&
                                      result.geometry!.location.lng != null) {
                                    plat = result.geometry!.location.lat;
                                    plang = result.geometry!.location.lng;
                                    
                                  } else {
                                  }
                                  setState(() {});
                                },
                                // initialPosition: LatLng(widget.position.latitude, widget.position.longitude),
                                initialPosition: LatLng(25.1756762, 51.1206243),
                                // useCurrentLocation: true,
                              )
```